# Failed to execute script {pygame.exe}

Tags: python, pygame

So I've made an game which just has a script named **"TrainYourBrain.py"**. I wanted to make an exe of it but I failed.

It just gives the error **Failed to execute script TrainYourBrain**

My game just has a single script with no audio files , images etc.

I'm using **python 3.8.4** and I've used **pyinstaller** for making an exe file

Here's my code :

```py
import pygame
import random
from pygame import mixer
import sys

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1260,900))
pygame.display.set_caption('MEMORY GAME')

run = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
dis_txt = "You will shown some random number and you'll"
dis_txt2 = 'be given 10 seconds to memorise them.'
dis_txt3 = 'Then enter the number which you had memorised'
time_strt = 6000
score = 0

input_num_Str = ''
rand_time = 5000

start = True
re = False
randm = True
input_usr = False
over = False
inp_rect = pygame.Rect(500 , 390 , 160 , 40)
num1 = 1
num2 = 10

#colors

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
grey = pygame.Color('grey12')

mus = True
class functions():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def screen_text(self,text,color,x,y,size):
        global txt
        font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',size)
        txt = font.render(text,True,color)
        screen.blit(txt, (x,y))

    def game_started(self):

        global start
        global time_strt
        global re

        while start:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            time_strt -= clock.tick(60)

            if time_strt <= 0:
                re = True
                start = False

            shourya.screen_text(dis_txt, grey, 260, 410, 34)
            shourya.screen_text(dis_txt2, grey, 320, 450, 34)
            shourya.screen_text(dis_txt3, grey, 240, 490, 34)
            pygame.display.update()

    def ready(self):

        global re
        ready = 2000

        while re:
            screen.fill(white)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            shourya.screen_text('Ready?',black,610,450,34)

            ready -= clock.tick(60)
            if ready <= 0:
                re = False
            pygame.display.update()

    def random_number(self,n1,n2):

        global randm
        global input_usr
        global rand_time
        global num
        num = random.randint(n1,n2)
        while randm:
            screen.fill(white)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            rand_time -= clock.tick(60)
            if rand_time <= 0:
                input_usr = True
                randm = False

            shourya.screen_text(str(num),black,630,450,33)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)

    def usr_input(self):

        global input_usr
        global inp_rect
        global input_num_Str
        global randm
        global num
        global num1
        global num2
        global rand_time
        global over
        global score

        while input_usr:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        input_num_Str = input_num_Str[:-1]
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        if input_num_Str == str(num):
                            num1 *= 10
                            num2 *= 10
                            score += 1
                            randm = True
                            input_usr = False
                            rand_time = 5000
                            input_num_Str = ''
                        else:
                            over = True
                            input_usr = False

                    else:
                        input_num_Str += event.unicode

            screen.fill(white)
            shourya.screen_text('Score : '+str(score),black,20,20,40)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(100,100,200),inp_rect,2)

            shourya.screen_text('ENTER THE NUMBER', black, 470, 230, 34)

            txt1 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',32)
            here = txt1.render(input_num_Str,True,black)
            screen.blit(here,(inp_rect.x + 10 ,inp_rect.y+5))
            inp_rect.w = here.get_width() + 16


            pygame.display.update()


    def game_over(self):

        global mus
        global num

        mixer.music.set_volume(0)

        if mus:


            mus = False
        screen.fill(white)
        shourya.screen_text('GAME OVER',(200,0,0),420,400,63)
        shourya.screen_text('Score : ' + str(score), black, 540, 480, 40)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)





shourya = functions()

while run:


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(white)
    shourya.game_started()
    shourya.ready()
    shourya.random_number(num1,num2)
    shourya.usr_input()
    if over:
        shourya.game_over()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

The game works fine as .py file but fails to run as an exe

What could've been causing the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: You are referencing a font file. Does changing to a system font or making sure the font file is found in the directory of the executable (or packed into the executable if that's possible with pyinstaller) the resolve the issue?

Comment: According to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017437/pyinstaller-failed-to-execute-script), there is probably a log that is produced somewhere. Please join this log to your question.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 I've tried everything , still the problem persists

Comment: What exactly is "everything"? "Everything" is a terrible description of things you have tried.

Comment: Tried whatever you said to try out

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal to see error message? Python wasn't created to build .exe files and tools like `pyinstaller` always have problem to recognized all files which it has to add to .exe (especially external C/C++ libraries which can be used by Python) If you use some resource - images, music, fonts then you may have to manually add them to config file created by `pyinstaller`. On `pyinstaller` page you should even find tutorial `what to do when exe doesn't work`

Comment: if you put code in class then you could use `self.` instead all these `global`